# Hibernate using old column mappings

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I recently changed some column names in my schema, and updated the hibernate mappings in correspondence to this change, but it seems as if the @JoinColumn mapping are using the old column names and not the new ones that have been entered.
Here is my mapping file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "matches")
public class MatchDao {
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String USER1_ID = "user1_id";
    public static final String USER2_ID = "user2_id";
    public static final String USER1_ROUND_ID = "user1_round_id";
    public static final String USER2_ROUND_ID = "user2_round_id";
    public static final String MATCH_START_DATE = "match_start_date";
    public static final String MATCH_COMPLETED_DATE = "match_completed_date";
    public static final String PLAYER1_MATCH_REPORT_SEEN = "player1_match_report_seen";
    public static final String PLAYER2_MATCH_REPORT_SEEN = "player2_match_report_seen";

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = ID)
    private int id;

    @JoinColumn(table = "user", referencedColumnName = UserDao.ID, name = USER1_ID, nullable = false)
    private Integer user1Id;

    @JoinColumn(table = "user", referencedColumnName = UserDao.ID, name = USER2_ID)
    private Integer user2Id;

    @JoinColumn(table = "round", referencedColumnName = RoundDao.ID, name = USER1_ROUND_ID)
    private Integer user1RoundId;

    @JoinColumn(table = "round", referencedColumnName = RoundDao.ID, name = USER2_ROUND_ID)
    private Integer user2RoundId;

    @Column(name = MATCH_START_DATE)
    private Date matchStartDate;

    @Column(name = MATCH_COMPLETED_DATE)
    private Date matchCompletedDate;

    @Column(name = PLAYER1_MATCH_REPORT_SEEN)
    private Date player1MatchReportSeen;

    @Column(name = PLAYER2_MATCH_REPORT_SEEN)
    private Date player2MatchReportSeen;
```

All 4 of the @JoinColumn variables seem to be using the old value, but the other mappings are using the new values.. has anyone seen this before?

Here is the sql query that gets generated:

```
select this_.id as id1_7_0_, this_.match_completed_date as match_co2_7_0_, this_.match_start_date as match_st3_7_0_, this_.player1_match_report_seen as player4_7_0_, this_.player2_match_report_seen as player5_7_0_, this_.user1Id as user6_7_0_, this_.user1RoundId as user7_7_0_, this_.user2Id as user8_7_0_, this_.user2RoundId as user9_7_0_ from matches this_
```

Comment: Can you tell us which column name you have changed ?

Comment: @Darshit all of them except the id column, I've switched from camel case to snake case.
I've even tested by changing the column name on user1_id to something like "blakfwefe" and it still uses user1Id... its like its being cached somewhere, i've done a full clean of classes before trying to run it again

Comment: What is the purpose of using the `@JoinColumn` annotation? Am I missing something?

Comment: @ujulu to be honest i originally had UserDao and RoundDao as the variable type but i changed it for a reason i can't remember, does the JoinColumn not enforce a foreign key relationship?

Comment: have just been playing around with it, seems if i change the variable name to user1_id it works.. for some reason the joinColumn annotation is taking the variable name rather than the annotated "name" parameter as the field name.
Does anyone know how to change this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of using JoinColumn is to define a foreign key to an associated table. In your case, I do not see any associated entities, so you don't need them. If the entity `MatchDao` has association to other entities you have to use these entities as fields instead and use an appropriate relationship annotation such as `@ManyToOne` depending on your requirement. If you do not have any relationship remove JoinColumn annotation and use `@Column` annotation instead.